# Java - Boolean not updating properly

Tags: java

Why my boolean is not updating properly?

```
public class Declarations {

    public static List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>(); //it is filled by FutureTasks (about 10)
    public static Boolean ready = true;

}

private class Stop {

    private void stop() {
        Declarations.ready = false;
        for(Future<?> f : futures) {
            f.cancel(true);
        }
    }

}

private class FutureTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            (...)
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if(ready) {
                System.out.println("Exception!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run stop() from Stop class I got "Exception!" in the output.
WHY? I'm changing ready boolean value so what's going on here?

Comment: 1. Please create and post a valid [mcve], code we can compile run and test. 2. Shouldn't ready be marked `volatile`?

Comment: I've made variable volatile and I'm sure that Declarations.ready = false; is executed

Comment: And yet you've not yet posted your MCVE, so if this hasn't solved your problem, you're making it hard if not impossible for us to help you, or for your question to help future visitors with similar problems.

Comment: If your field is not updating then there are two possibilities: (1) its state was cached by thread and wasn't updated as fast as you wanted, making it volatile should prevent it (2) your code doesn't change it (maybe you are never calling `stop()` method because something which you are not showing us prevents it). Anyway we can't be sure what is wrong without seeing proper [mcve].

Comment: Please add the code in the try.. we can't assist if we don't know what is causing the exception. This is a concurrent visibility issue - i.e. the thread calling the stop() method is possibly changing the ready to false, but the thread running the task is not seeing the update.

Comment: Also, why not print the stack trace within your catch block?

Comment: Try: `volatile AtomicBoolean ready`? Also is there a reason why your variables are static?

Comment: `"Will do. Wait a minute"` -- any time that you're ready

Comment: Also waiting for your update :) regards "Will do. Wait a minute"

Answer (score 3):

You don't have any synchronization, and your `ready` is not volatile, so changes made to it in one thread are not even guaranteed to be **ever** visible by other threads.

Try making it `volatile`.

Some documentation on synchronization: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1

Comment: Changed and it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the entire code, so it's hard to understand what's going on.

I suggest you debug your code or add a printout after "Declarations.ready = false;" to understand whether it's executed or not.

Also, it's unclear if it's running on a single thread, or in parallel in multiple threads.

Comment: I've added System.out.println(ready); directly before making it false and it is still the same. I mean ready is printed